# Helpful tasks for MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm just learning about MSBuild and I'm wondering what are some useful tasks people use MSBuild scripts for?

I've gone through the Microsoft documentation, just interested in some real world uses.

Comment: Also check out NAnt, an open source alternative. http://nant.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you check out [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/). There's a number of good ones in the package. I personally use the NUnit task, amongst others.